# How to make my output have space(even and odd number )

Tags: c++, c

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < conio.h >
#define BILMAX 10

int main()
{
int num[BILMAX],i;
printf("insert 10 number and separated by space:\n");
for (i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&num[i]);}
printf("\n\nEven Number : \n");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
if(num[i] % 2==0)
printf("%d",num[i]);
}
printf("\n\nOdd Number : \n");
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++)
{
if(num[i] % 2 !=0)
printf("%d",num[i]);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

***my output is like this***

> insert 10 number and separated by space:
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> Even Number:
>
> 246810
>
> Odd Number:
>
> 13579

***i want my output like this***

> insert 10 number and separated by space:
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> Even Number:
>
> 2 4 6 8 10
>
> Odd Number:
>
> 1 3 5 7 9

***i want my output have a space.***

***Please help***

Comment: Turn `"%d"` into `"%d "`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to print a space after each number, change this line:

```
printf("%d",num[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%d ",num[i]);
```

Notice the space after `%d`.

Comment: It seems like the asker fundamentally doesn't understand what `printf` is doing. Perhaps a blurb to help them out?

Answer (score 0):

Space an be inserted in a printf just by leaving a simple blank between quotes: " "

Just like printing your first program "Hello World" (space between Hello and World). Whatever you type inside the code it gets printed as it is.

For printing a space after each number do this

```
printf("%d ",num[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Space can be provided by using escape sequence \t `printf("%d \t",num[i]);`