# how do i get the sum of two dimensional matrix?

Tags: c++

```
#include < stdio.h >
#define n 10

int main()
{

    float A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n], m;
    int i,j;
  char answer;

    printf ("\xB1\xB1 total 2 matriks \xB1\xB1");

  /*Input dimensi matriks*/

    printf ("\n\nInput dimensi matriks(1-10) :");
    scanf ("%f",&m);

    /*Input elemen matriks A */

    printf ("\n\nMatriks A :");

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
      printf ("\nBaris ke-%d\n",i+1);
         for (j=0;j<m;j++)
         {
          printf ("\tElemen [%d][%d] :",i+1,j+1);
              scanf ("%f",&A[i][j]);
          }
    }

    /*Input elemen matriks B */

    printf ("\n\nMatriks B :");

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
      printf ("\nLine ke-%d\n",i+1);
         for (j=0;j<m;j++)
      {
              printf ("\tElemen [%d][%d] :",i+1,j+1);
          scanf ("%f",&B[i][j]);
              }
  }
    /*total matriks A dan B */

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
  for (j=0;j<m;j++)
    C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];

  /*Print Output*/

    printf ("\n\nTotal Matriks A dan B adalah :");
  for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
         printf ("\n");
         for (j=0;j<m;j++)
         printf ("%12.3f",C[i][j]);
         }

         printf ("\n\nPress any button");


         return 0;
}
```

***this is my output***

addition 2 matricks

input  dimension matriks (1-10) :2

matrics A

line 1-

Element [1][1]:1

Element [2][2]:2

line 2-

Element [1][1]:1

Element [2][2]:2

Matrics B

line 1-

Element [1][1]:1

Element [2][2]:2

line 2-

Element [1][1]:1

Element [1][1]:2

total of Matrics A and B is:

2.000     4.000

2.000     4.000

***i want my output like this no(.000)***

2         4

2         4

Comment: Your `"%12.3f"` specifically request 3 digits after the integral component... take out the `.3` if that's unwanted, or switch to C++ iostreams and use `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` etc..

Comment: Funny, just out of the top of my mind I feel like this is a clone of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158869/how-to-make-my-output-have-spaceeven-and-odd-number) other user/question asked 15 min ago, ha :P. The post formating is the same, the code formatting is the same, and the lack of effort is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    printf ("%12.3f",C[i][j]);
```

To

```
    printf ("%12.0f",C[i][j]);
```

The number after the decimal in the format specifier tells printf how many digits to include.

Google: "printf format specifier" for more details.

Comment: tq very much for help me guys